# Red vid How focus changed from one field to another with press enter

Tags: red

```
View [
     f1:  field focus
     f2:  field
]
```

When run this code cursor get focus in `f1`
But I want to press enter and focus will be in `f2`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a set-focus f2 command in red?

Comment: No built-in `set-focus` function yet.

Comment: Ok, now [it has](https://github.com/red/red/commit/4e621a9a899c613a9538105464c04a9da7e0157c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside a `on-enter` handler, you need to change the [`selected`](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/view.html#_window) facet of the window face (just the parent face in this case) to point to the face you want to focus on. So your code becomes:

```
view [ f1: field focus on-enter [face/parent/selected: f2] f2: field ]
```

If you need to change focus often, you can define a convenient shortcut function:

```
set-focus: function [face [object!]][
    p: face/parent
    while [p/type <> 'window][p: p/parent]
    p/selected: face
]

view [ f1: field focus on-enter [set-focus f2] f2: field ]
```

Red/View will provide a built-in `set-focus` function in future versions, so you won't have to define it in your own code.

Comment: It's my pleasure to have response from the father of red . thanks